# synchorised static method vs synchronise class object

Tags: java, static, synchronize

Suppose my `Foo` class looked like this

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void func_1() { /* do something */ }
    public static void func_2() { /* do something */ }
}
```

and  that my `Bar` class looked like this

```
public class Bar
{
    public void method_1()
    {
         synchronized(Foo.class)
         {
             Foo.func_1();
         } 
    }          
}
```

Now instead of locking `Foo.class` object in `Bar.method_1`, could I have declared `Foo.func_1` and `Foo.func_2` as `synchronized`, and still archived the same purpose?

Thank you

Comment: The same object is used for the sychronization, but with synchronized static methods, the caller does not perform the synchronization so that technique may be preferable (the caller can never forget to perform synchronization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they achieve the same thing -- locking `Foo.class`.  Here's the relevant excerpt from the [Java Language Specification, Section 8.4.3.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6):

> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class
>   object for the method's class is used.

Using `synchronized` on the static `func_1()` or `func_2()` methods in your `Foo` class locks the `Foo.class` implicitly, while `synchronized(Foo.class)` locks it explicitly.

Comment: Good job, I didn't know this and I've been using the language for a while. Usually don't synchronize on static classes...

Comment: Which one is the better (ie., cleaner, easier to read) practice?

Comment: I believe it's standard Java knowledge to know that a `static synchronized` method locks its class's `Class` object.  It's easier for a caller to read the Javadocs to see that the method is `synchronized` than to dig into your actual code to see how thread safety is achieved.  So I would say that making the method synchronized is better practice here.

Answer (score 3):

A static synchronized method obtains lock on class and by taking lock on `Foo.class` , you are doing same thing. So yes they will achieve same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are pretty much the same. The only difference is : in one case lock is acquired before calling the method and in another it is acquired later.